# matlab coding n-dimensional function

Tags: matlab, function

I'm looking for an easy way to to code a function in matlab that takes a vector (array) as input and gives a vector (array) as output.

If the input and output arrays are small, it's easy to code with function handles:

```matlab
f=@(u)[u(1),u(2)]
```

This approach doesn't work for me for large vectors, as it does not enable me to specify each component of the output array in a loop.

I found a way to make it work, but it is very ugly: chaining together the whole function as a string, then converting it to a function:

```
str2fun(strcat('@(u)[u(',int2str(1),'), u(',int2str(2),')]'))
```

Example:

```matlab
n=100; input=zeros(1,n);
str=strcat('@(u)[cos(u(',int2str(1),')),');
for i=2:n-1
    str=strcat(str,'cos(u(',int2str(i),'))^',int2str(i),',');
end
str=strcat(str,'cos(u(',int2str(n),'))^',int2str(n),']');
f=str2func(str);

f(input)
```

output is a 100-element vector of ones.

The code generates a function handle that takes an n-long vector and returns an n-long vector.
It is important that i can control which elements of the input should each element of the output depend on.

This way of constructing the function seems really ugly and complicated, i'd like to know if there is a better way to code such functions in matlab?

Comment: [1,1,1,1,1,1,...,1], what the example gives if it is executed

Comment: I think this is a minimal working example.The example works for "longer" functions too, but the more involved the mathematical formula is to compute the substitution the less readable and more prone to errors this way of coding it becomes. .

Comment: You need to read [this page of the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-functions-in-files.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code can be vectorised as below:

```
f = @(u) cos(u).^(1:numel(u));
```